# How to obtain the minimum number of individuals needed to estimate a character frequency

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, mean, computational-statistics, frequency

I have 150 individuals coming from the same population. I want to know what is the minimum number of individuals I need to estimate the frequency for ~1600 different characters.
Each character can have a value of 0, 0.5, 1 or NA (couldn't be calculated). This means that the number of individuals used for each character can be different. The frequency, calculated as the mean from all individuals will always be a number between 0 and 1.

I can see how frequencies change and compare them to the ones using 150 individuals by randomly subtracting individuals but I want to do (and understand) a more formal approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have 150 observations already why not use all of them?

Comment: Fair point. I want to know what is the minimum number of individuals to calculate the frequencies in other populations where I don't have that many individuals. Basically I want to know if I can trust the calculations done in the other populations.

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it seems that what you want to do is, given a new sample from a new population, estimate the uncertainty in your estimate of the mean value of a certain characteristic. The usual way to do this is to calculate a confidence interval for the mean. You can use bootstrapping to do that without assuming a particular parametric model.

Comment: The problem is that I have ~1600 means with their corresponding CI calculated using a different number of individuals. Where do I set the threshold?

Comment: @biojl What threshold, the confidence level of the confidence intervals? You can use 95% for all of them.

Comment: I need to use the same number of individuals for all the calculations. Therefore if I simply use 95% I will get a very high number of individuals because some characters will have a very large CI.

Comment: @biojl I don't understand. A CI in this context wouldn't give you a number of individuals; it would give you a proposed range for the mean. Also, you keep saying "character" when you seem to mean "characteristic" or "feature".

Comment: yes, you are right, it will return a range for the mean, I should have written "I will get a large CI and if I want to narrow it I will have to use a very high number of individuals.". I think you can imply those things from the text. Obviously I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @biojl Them's the breaks—if you want precise estimates, you need bigger samples. If you're stuck with the sample sizes you have, then you're stuck with wide CIs.